# Is it possible to make a macro or similar to download all images from the metropolitan museum website

Tags: java, html, imacros

I was wondering if it's possible to make a macro to download every image from the metropolitan museum image collection http://www.metmuseum.org/collection/the-collection-online

I don't really have any idea how to program macros, but just wondering if anyone would be able to help. I want to create a backup database of the important artworks they have for download. They are all free to the public.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: So basically you want someone to write a program for you.

Answer (score 0):

The macro below downloads all available images from the given page. Run it in cycle with the number of steps equal to number of images on this web-site page (by default 30). (For better automation one has to use iMacros Scripting Interface (e.g. JavaScript) but in this case the code will be larger.)

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO 
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

' first page to download the images (as an example)
SET pageToDnl http://www.metmuseum.org/collection/the-collection-online/search?ft=john+la+farge&noqs=true
TAB T=1
URL GOTO={{pageToDnl}}
SET !LOOP 1
SET refPos EVAL(2*({{!LOOP}}-1)+1)
TAG POS={{refPos}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:*?rpp=30&pg=1&ft=john+la+farge&pos=* EXTRACT=HREF
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO={{!EXTRACT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=HREF:http://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/*/web-large/*.jpg CONTENT=EVENT:SAVETARGETAS
TAB CLOSE
```